Book trilogy before 1990s set in the future in space
The protagonist is a man, there is a space army, he lands a spaceship in manual saving lots of people, but the army still have a problem with him.
There’s a female protagonist who is by the book, she has a single adjustment to her uniform, in this case hair, allowed in peace time.  Dyed I think.
The antagonist is a woman, possibly an alien, maybe a reveal in the third part.  At the end of the first book she teleports away to save herself and ends up looking older as a price to pay.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the covers of any of the books?
